# DocuSign Connect sends duplicate webhook calls when envelope has multiple recipients

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

In my DocuSign application, I have two recipients that sign documents. When both recipients finish signing the envelope, DocuSign Connect dispatches two identical XML payloads, at what appears to be exactly the same time. This causes issues with my application because I don't want my logic to be duplicated. Is this is a bug in the DocuSign Connect, or is it intentional? I don't think DocuSign duplicated calls when I set up my application two years ago.

Here's an example envelope that appears in the Connect logs in my account:

First webhook call
`<TimeGenerated>2020-04-13T10:34:19.1110424</TimeGenerated>`

Second webhook call
`<TimeGenerated>2020-04-13T10:34:19.1110424</TimeGenerated>`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your own questions and upvote any useful answer you find on StackOverflow. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're requesting recipient completion events then you shouldn't be surprised to get two notifications, one for each of the two recipients.

They can be the exact same since the default queuing strategy for Connect is for the notification message to reflect the envelope's status at the time the notification is sent, not the status at the time the event triggered.

Suggestions:

1. Switch to the new queuing strategy, SIM (Send Intermediate Messages). Do this from the Admin tool, in the Updates section.
2. Only request the envelope completion event, not the recipient completion event.
3. Update your app to more flexibly handle the notifications. Note that with the default queuing strategy, a recipient completed event will often be skipped in favor of an envelope completion event (if you're asking for both envelope and recipient completion event notification).